# Activerecord how to get all unique belongs_to attributes in a set?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, information-retrieval

I have a rails application with a model Posts and a model Categories.

Category belongs_to Post

I'm using pagination to display 20 posts per page, and each page I have a filter to filter by categories.

As of now, I print out the list of categories based on the whole set of posts, not the subset that constitutes the given paginated page.

So when in my action I was previously doing:

```
home do
  @posts = Posts.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
  @categories = Category.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

How can I populate @categories such that it contains a list of all the unique categories from @posts, rather than from the whole database of Categories.

Comment: you want unique `posts` or `categories` ?  or do you mean something like `Category.joins(:posts).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20).uniq`

Comment: Thanks, please post an answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try as `Category.joins(:posts).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20).uniq`.